# Is it possible in an ionic 3 app to overlay a transparent png over the phone screen while taking a picture

Tags: ionic3

I work to an ionic 3 app and I want, while I' taking a picture to overlay a transparent .png on phone's screen.
Actually, I want to be able to suggest - using a circle for example - where  someone's face  should be positioned while taking a selfie.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can, but not with the out-of-the-box cordova camera library. You'll have to use a plugin such as : https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview

This guide goes about overlaying some HTML on it. https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-go-create-a-pokemon-go-style-interface-in-ionic-2/ You could try changing the transparency on the HTML to get that transparent effect.